# Hibernate Criteria Query - How to search through many-to-many with attributes?

Tags: nhibernate, activerecord, criteria, castle-activerecord

I'm trying to create a Criteria query to select objects that are related via an association table.

```
Insurer * - 1 Insurer_Section 1 - * Section
```

InsurerSection has an association attribute: active:bool.

How do I get all Insurers whose active attribute in the InsurerSection class is set to true?

PS: I can't go like this:

```
Insurer.FindAll(
DetachedCriteria.For<Insurer>().CreateCriteria("Insurer_Section").Add(Expression.Eq("Active", true)
);
```

because Insurer_Section is an association table that is only mapped via HasAndBelongsToMany:

```
[HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(Section), Table = "`Insurer_Section`", 
            ColumnKey = "`IdInsurer`", ColumnRef = "`IdSection`",
            Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.AllDeleteOrphan)]
        private IList<Section> Sections {
            get { return this.sections; }
            set { this.sections = value; }
        }
```

AND

```
[HasAndBelongsToMany(typeof(Insurer), Table = "`Insurer_Section`",
            ColumnKey = "`IdSection`", ColumnRef = "`IdInsurer`",
            Cascade = ManyRelationCascadeEnum.None, Inverse = true)]
        public IList<Insurer> Insurers {
            get { return this.insurers; }
            set { this.insurers = value; }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that, if you association table has properties you need you must map the association as a one-to-many (to an new enity for Insurer_Section) that then has a many-to-one 
relation to Section.

The moment the association table becomes more than just a the primary keys and possible index columns you will need to map the association table as a separate entity linking the two entities (Insurer and Section together with the association information, like IsActive)

Answer (score 0):

Torkel is correct.  You need to not only create the new linking entity, but also change the collection for each of the entities to a collection of your new linking entity.  Then change the mappings as appropriate.